# Unique token using uuid is generating same codes

Tags: django, ajax, model, token, uuid

im using uuid token to activate users account , so every client created have their own code in the Client model , but when i create new client it generate always the same Token as others , i have used the uuid 4 , is their anyother ways to generate unique client code to activate their account or some other method then uuid , or just im missing a point on how to generate uuid on models ,
their is my model and client creation codes :

Model.py :

```
def generateUUID():
return str(uuid4())

class client(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=85)
date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
height = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
weight = models.IntegerField(null=True , blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
picture = models.URLField(null=True ,blank=True)
affiliation = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="client_coach")
reference = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True , blank=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
token = models.CharField( max_length=85, default=generateUUID())


def __str__(self):
   return self.name

def getname(self):
    return self.coach.name
```

view.py:

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['action'] == 'client':
    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    print(form)
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    email = request.POST.get('email')

    #client_code = code.objects.create()

    new_client = client.objects.create(name = name, email = email, affiliation = request.user)
    new_client.save()
    return JsonResponse({'client': model_to_dict(new_client)}, status=200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom `save` method and assign this there.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.token = generateUUID()
    super(client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thankss , i have created 5 new client and all tokens are different , its work well